# How to change the stock reservation in Magento from pending to processing?

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I prevent Magento from reserving product stock on "pending" orders. Generally allow stock quantity reservation for paid orders only.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done without code changes.

In Order to generally prevent Magento from subtracting stock quantity from products you may use system configuration field "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" set to "no" under System Config->Catalog->Inventory

**To achieve desired behaviour you may try following Solution:**

- Disable default magento behaviour by setting "Decrease Stock..." to
  "no"
- Create new local Module
- Add Observer for event sales_order_save_after
- Compare status values and decrease stock when needed

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply, but that is not quite what I need...
I don't need to change the status of the order, I just need Magento not to save stock for pending orders...

Comment: ok, that more different behaviour. I will try to answer separately